# JSTree - DND Not Honoring Return

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm stuck guys, I hope someone can help me figure this out. I have three node types that I'm populating JStree with.

- Folder
- Project
- Job

I have some rules that need to be considered when trying to drag and drop one node into another.

- Folders can have children of type "folder" & "project"
- Projects can only have children of type "job"
- Jobs cannot have any children

Problem: JSTree ignores the boolean values I'm returning and allows DND for all elements. Normally returning "false" would set the red X and also disallow a drop, this is not the case. I've written the return of my function checkNodeCB() to the console and my true/false logic appears to be sound. See my code below:

```
  core: {
     check_callback: function(e,node,parent,position,more){
        function checkNodeCB(oNode,tNode){
          if(tNode.type === "folder" && oNode.type !== "job"){
             //console.log("I want to place a "+oNode.type+" inside a folder");
             return true;
          }
          if(tNode.type === "project" && oNode.type === "job"){
             //console.log("I want to place a job under a project");
             return true;
          }
          return false;
        };
        if((e === 'copy_node' || e === 'move_node') && more.dnd){
           if (oldNode !== more.ref.id){
              oldNode = more.ref.id; //Set the oldNode to the current ID so it no longer executes
              //console.log(checkNodeCB(node.original,more.ref.original));
              return checkNodeCB(node.original,more.ref.original);
           }
        }
        return true;
     },
     worker: true
  },
  dnd:{
     check_while_dragging:true
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Like every moment of enlightenment, I stepped away to take care of mother nature and realized what I was doing wrong. I was trying to make my code more efficient by only executing the checkNodeCB() function when my mouse moved over a different node and neglected to take into account that the return was still being set to true outside the function. The code is not perfect, but this is what I ended up with.

```
     check_callback: function(e,node,parent,position,more){
        function checkNodeCB(oNode,tNode){
          if(tNode.type === "folder" && oNode.type !== "job"){
             outPut = true;
          }
          if(tNode.type === "project" && oNode.type === "job"){
             outPut = true;
          }else{
             outPut = false;
          }
        };
        if((e === 'copy_node' || e === 'move_node') && more.dnd){
           if (oldNode !== more.ref.id){
              oldNode = more.ref.id; //Set the oldNode to the current ID so it no longer executes
              checkNodeCB(node.original,more.ref.original);
           }
           return outPut; //Use the output variable so the state persists when moving the mouse over the current "hovered" node
        }
        return true;
     },
```